# Is it possible to replace the SATA CD-ROM to SATA HDD\SSD on my dell R610?

Tags: dell, sata

Like many people, I do not use a CD-ROM on my server is it possible to replace the SATA CD-ROM  to SATA HDD\SSD on my dell R610?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give some more information about why you'd need to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not.

While there is nothing preventing you from hooking a SATA device other than an optical drive up to the SATA port for the optical drive, the engineering of your 1U server is so tight that there's nowhere to physically mount the drive.

Unless you can find a hard drive or SSD that has the same physical form factor as the slim line OD, you'll just have to make do with the six drive bays you have.

If you absolutely need to hook another drive up, I would suggest a USB to SATA cable, or looking into something like NAS or a SAN.

Comment: You realise that adapters for fitting 2.5" disks into the form factor for slim optical drives are extremely common?

Comment: They may be much more common now than when the question was first posed...*shrug*

Comment: They were common at least back in 2011 (I bought one at that time).